# Trouble getting an answer to this bessel function in Maple 2015

Tags: maple

I'm trying to define a function `h` as a bessel function in the form:

```
h:=x-> (int(cos(x*sin(y)), y = 0 .. pi))/pi;
```

and then finding a value for x=0 with:

```
h(0);
```

But it's returning `h(0)` straight back at me.

I've also tried rephrasing the equation and defining the function in different ways and calling it with the subs command.

I'm fairly new to maple so is there something blaringly obvious I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Just copying and pasting your two lines of code gives me `h(0) = 1`. That makes sense since the integrand is just 1. You can see that by using a capital "i" in `int`, i.e. `h:=x-> (Int(cos(x*sin(y)), y = 0 .. pi))/pi;` and then do `h(0);value(%);`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply man! I'm going to try running maple on a different machine as I just can't seem to get a value.

Comment: Just to add it now works thank you very much!!